# ColdFusion 11 with Standalone Solr Pre-install

Tags: solr, coldfusion

I need to install Solr on its own server for scalability/multiple CF connections. However I am confused as to how CF 11 does this. The Standalone services installer seems to be for the Express Install.

Adobe does not support a non-ColdFusion Solr install. So do I need to install a full CF 11 install on my Solr server and open it up for remote connection?

Or do I use CF Express with the stand-alone installer?

This is running a legacy application, and I need to mimic a normal coldfusion install as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact use a non-ColdFusion Solr install with ColdFusion.  Using the CFSolrLib library, you can interact with an external Solr server using the component included in the library.  I'm personally running Solr 5.2 with a ColdFusion 11 application using this library.

http://cfsolrlib.riaforge.org/

Comment: That will be great for future deployments, however this is a legacy app. I cannot make changes to it now.

Comment: That does limit your options.  In CF 11, the Solr service is no longer separate.  It's lumped into an "Add on services pack" like you mentioned above.  That standalone services pack can be installed by itself on a remote server.  No need to install full CF.  Just point your Solr config to the correct IP address in your CF Administrator after you install and you should be functional.

Comment: Oh, and by default, the CF 11 Solr service uses port 8987, so make sure you have that one open between the two servers.